# What is count[str.charAt(i)]++ actually storing?

Tags: java, data-structures

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

This question was actually solved by me after I looked at the solution. But I do not get what is happening in the getCharOccur function. Explicitly, what exactly is getting stored in count[str.charAt(i)]++. What are the indexes and the values inside that array. Also in the beginning why are we declaring count[] as a dynamic array with 256 character empty array? I tried printing the count[str.charAt(i)]++ but it shows some null values in the console.

```
public class Main {
    static final int chars=256;
    static char count[]=new char[chars];

    //calculating the number of occurences of each character
      static void getCharOccur(String str){
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;

        }
    }

    //Calculating index of first non repeating character
    static int getNonRepeatChar(String str){
        getCharOccur(str);
        int index=-1;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            if(count[str.charAt(i)]==1){
                index=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="thisisit";
        int index=getNonRepeatChar(str);
        System.out.println(index==-1 ? "Either all characters are 
        "repeating character is  "+str.charAt(index));

    }
}
```

The results were valid as it printed: First non repeating character is  h

Comment: you forgot to post the code of `getCharOccur()`...

Answer (score 0):

a `char` is just an unsigned integer which represents a unicode character.

You can also use it as a number, it starts at `\u0000` and if you increment it you can get `\u0001` you can also do maths on it like any number.

Here is an example for which I have attached a video explaining it.

https://twitter.com/PeterLawrey/status/1131620691906891777

NOTE: `char` overflows after 65535 so is not a good choice, apart from the fact it's confusing. Using an `int[]` would have been a better choice.